# php How to make title tag based on php variable

Tags: html, tags, title, var

How would I make my title tag based off my php variable.

Right now I have this to try to pull my title tag from my php variable, but it doesn't work.

`<title><?php echo htmlentities($title); ?></title>`

Generally they fill out a form for a question they have then somebody answers it. Here is the variables for that.

```
$topic_name = breakLongWords($_REQUEST["topic_name"], 20, " ");
        $topic_email = breakLongWords($_REQUEST["topic_email"], 30, " ");
        $topic_title = breakLongWords($_REQUEST["topic_title"], 20, " ");
        $topic_text = breakLongWords($_REQUEST["topic_text"], 30, " ");

        $topic_title = ($title);
```

So they topic title should equal $title

but it isnt loading the $title as a title tag in html. How would I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: why are you using htmlentities here? give an example of what you are passing.

Comment: I dont know I guess I don't need it. Do you have a solution to the problem though if I removed it?